# C++ vector iterator

Tags: c++, vector

I need some help in understanding what is happening to the vector `rvN`

This is my understanding:

rvN is a vector containing the number characters 0001. 
In the function `Clear()`, all of the leading zeroes are to be erased from the vector. The iterator is set to pointing to past the end of the last vector element (1).

```
it = 3

*it != 0  (since *it == 1)

rvN.erase(it+1, rvN.end()) ->>> rvN.erase(4,rvN.end()) ?
```

How are all of the zeroes eliminated?

```
for (int i = Number.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (Number[i]<'0' || Number[i]>'9')
            break;
        else
            rvN.push_back(Number[i] - '0');
    }
    Clear(rvN);
}

    void LargeNumber::Clear(vector<char>& rvN)
    {
        //Eliminate all leading 0s
        vector<char>::iterator it = rvN.end();
        while (it != rvN.begin())
        {
            it--;
            if (*it != 0)
                break;
        }
        rvN.erase(it + 1, rvN.end());
    }
```

Comment: The vector appears to be reversed, so that the least significant value is stored at the "begin" end. E.g. 1234 is stored as { 4, 3, 2, 1 }. Presumably, 'reverse vector Numbers'

Comment: Have you see this code work? What is the block before the code with it=3 in it describing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The digits are read from right to left:

```
for (int i = Number.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

If "Number" contains "1234" the first digit read will be the least-significant, i.e. "4". These are then pushed onto "rvN" in the order they are read. As a result, rvN would become

```
{ 4, 3, 2, 1 }
```

or if Number contained 00005

```
{ 5, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

So Clear is simply working from right-to-left until it finds a non zero and then trimming the back of the array to leave only the right-most digits in the normal representation (050 -> 50, 005 -> 5, 500 -> 500).

Comment: Number is 1000. So if reversed, it would be 0001. If it is working from right to left, how are the zeroes before 1 removed? Since it reaches 1 first and breaks out of the while loop. I'm a little confused.

Comment: @Justin They're not. Thats the point. If the number is `"1000"` the zeros are significant. If the number were `"0001"` the reversal would be `1000` then the loop would iterate four times, keeping the last test and thus returning `1`. The only way you get `0001` as `rvN` to begin with is if the original data was `"1000"`.

Comment: Edited the last line of my answer slightly.